# linear algebra in python

Tags: linear-algebra, python

Given a tall $m \times n$ matrix $X$, I need to calculate $s = 1 + x(X^t X)^{-1}x^t$. Here, $x$ is a row vector. Is there an efficient (or, recommended) way to compute this in python?

Needless to say, $X^t X$ will be symmetric positive definite.

My attempt:

If we consider the QR decomposition of $X$, i.e., $X = QR$, where $Q$ is orthogonal, $R$ is upper triangular, then $X^t X = R^t R.$

QR decomposition can be easily obtained using

Q, R = numpy.linalg.qr(X)

But then again, is there a particularly efficient way to calculate $(R^t R)^{-1}$?

Comment: efficient in what way? Time or memory expenses? Or as little code as possible? Is $m>n$ or the other way?

Comment: m is much greater than n, i.e., m >> n. Like I said, it's a 'tall' matrix. Efficient -- certainly in time. If possible in memory, too. No, 'little code' is not what I thought about. But I know that using inbuilt python commands, especially numpy, is always more efficient (in both time and memory).

Comment: There is zero reason to calculate the inverse explicitly. You're way better off calculating a Cholesky decomposition and then using it to quickly find solutions.

Comment: Yes, that is a general true. You *never* compute the inverse, but rather solve a linear algebraic problem. In other words, if you want to compute $A^{-1}y$ you are alway better of solving $Ax=y$.

Comment: I don't need just the solution. I need it for the scaling factor in a rank one update formula. The scaling factor looks like this: $$ s = 1 + x^t(X^tX)^{-1} x.$$

Comment: @ not computing the inverse to solve a linear system: yes, I totally know that. This is part of a pre-existing algorithm that I am implementing for some reason.

Comment: Given x, solve $(X^{T}X)z=x$, then $s=1+x^{T}z$.  There's no need to compute the inverse.

Comment: If you are going to use computers why code for finding inverse of a matrix (rediscovering wheel).  Use SAGE software (www.sagemath.org). Most matrix algorithms are already available as library function. You write your code at a much higher level and get to use your favourite Python. (SAGE uses Python as glue).

Comment: @ P Vanchinathan:  I'm not going to write the code for finding the inverse of a matrix. I'm just looking for an efficient way to do that computation using inbuilt commands in python. Basically, a way of avoiding computing the inverse. No ... I won't be using sage.

Comment: I'm doing it the way Brian Borchers suggested. Thank you! I am not able to mark your answer as 'accepted'. It looks like 'comments' don't have that option? or do they?

Comment: @rgupta: It would be better if you updated the question to show what you really want (the update formula).

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, any preprocessing such as QR decomposition, will make the computation substantionally more time and memory expensive, espeially for large $m$. For sure, QR decomposition works as a normalization in matrix computations and you can avoid some numerical instability problems with it, but I don't think it is of much use in this situtation. Hence, I would probably perform the matrix-matrix product $X^TX

Regarding the inverse, if you do need the matrix itself for some reason, you can either solve $n$ linear equations $X^TX=e_i$ for $i=1,\dotsc ,n$ or you can use the [SVD](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html) implemented in python for amtrix $X$. That is stable, but rather costly once again. However it provides complete knowledge of the operator $X^TX$, since you obtain the spectral decomposition in this way and at the same time you also have a complete knowledge about $X$, which may come handy, depending on the algorithm.

Comment: Generally it is considered a numerical faux pas to form the product $X^T X$.